# Ignore all on set of words (ASPELL)

Tags: bash, aspell

How can I tell aspell to ignore given set of words.

I do need pass that list as input parameter, so I don't need to put ignore all interactively.

As I have a loop for over 100 files in which I call aspell to check the syntax on each one.

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945040/spell-checking-ignore-set-of-words).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a file similar to the following:

```
personal_ws-1.1 en 2
wlkju
yytuvze
```

Replace "en" with the language you're using and "2" with the number of words in the list. I've shown two nonsense words, but your list should consist of one word per line in a similar manner.

Save the file with a name such as `.aspell.en.pws`.

This is an example command using a personal word list such as the one above:

```
$ echo 'foo yytuvze bar baz banana wlkju' | aspell -a --personal=./.aspell.en.pws --dont-suggest
@(#) International Ispell Version 3.1.20 (but really Aspell 0.60.6)
*
*
*
# baz 16
*
*
```